# replace specific values of a specific line from a file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've created a GUI using Tkinter. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
def execute():
import os
os.chdir("batfile")
os.system("open.bat")

def calculations():
shaftdia = float(e1.get())
outdia = 2 * shaftdia
 thickfork = 0.75*shaftdia
 thicksingleye = 1.75*shaftdia
 diapin = shaftdia
 diapincollar = 1.5*shaftdia

 Label(master, text="{} ".format(str(outdia))).grid(row=5, column = 2, pady=5)
 Label(master, text="{} ".format(str(thickfork))).grid(row=6, column=2, pady=5)
 Label(master, text="{} ".format(str(thicksingleye))).grid(row=7, column=2, pady=5)
 Label(master, text="{} ".format(str(shaftdia))).grid(row=8, column=2, pady=5)
 Label(master, text="{} ".format(str(diapincollar))).grid(row=9, column=2, pady=5)

 print("Outer diameter of eye: %f" % float(outdia))
 print("Thickness of fork: %f" % float(thickfork))
 print("Thickness of single eye: %f" % float(thicksingleye))
 print("Diameter of pin: %f" % float(diapin))
 print("Diameter of knuckle pin and collar: %f" % float(diapincollar))
 pass


Label(master, text="Shaft Diameter").grid(row=4, pady=5)
Label(master, text="Outer diameter of eye").grid(row=5, pady=5)
Label(master, text="Thickness of fork").grid(row=6, pady=5)
Label(master, text="Thickness of single eye").grid(row=7, pady=5)
Label(master, text="Diameter of Pin").grid(row=8, pady=5)
Label(master, text="Diameter of knuckle pin head and collar").grid(row=9, pady=5)

 e1 = Entry(master)
 e1.grid(row=4, column=2)

Button(master, text='CALCULATE', command=calculations).grid(row=10, column=0)
Button(master, text='CREATE', command=execute).grid(row=10, column=1)

master.mainloop( )
```

After giving some input in shaft diameter I get certain values of outer diameter of eye, thickness of fork and etc. I want this value to replace the previous values present in the file.
Consider the file is .txt file which contains the following text:

```
Outer diameter of eye = 20
Thickness of fork = 7.5
Thickness of single eye = 17.5
Diameter of pin = 10
Diameter of knuckle pin and collar = 15
```

I want to replace these dimensions with the new dimensions that are generated

Comment: So the question basically is to replace the values in the txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the values placed in a txt file, that needs a change.

list.txt:

```
Outer diameter of eye = 20
Thickness of fork = 7.5
Thickness of single eye = 17.5
Diameter of pin = 10
Diameter of knuckle pin and collar = 15
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

# list of new Values
newVal_list = [23,54,67,19.43,4]
i = 0
for line in content:
    find_TC = line.find('=')

    if find_TC > 0:
        x = line.split('=', 1)[1]

        print(line.replace(x,str(newVal_list[i])))   # for replacing
        print("Old Value: {}, New Value: {}".format(x, newVal_list[i]))
        i += 1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Old Value:  20, New Value: 23
Old Value:  7.5, New Value: 54
Old Value:  17.5, New Value: 67
Old Value:  10, New Value: 19.43
Old Value:  15, New Value: 4
```

**EDIT:**

To search and replace the values in the same file using `fileinput`:

```
import fileinput

# list of new Values
newVal_list = [23,54,67,19.43,4]
i = 0
with fileinput.FileInput(logFile, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        find_TC = line.find('=')
        if find_TC > 0:
            x = line.split('=', 1)[1]
            line = line.replace(x, " " + str(newVal_list[i]))
            print(line)
            i += 1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Outer diameter of eye = 23
Thickness of fork = 54
Thickness of single eye = 67
Diameter of pin = 19.43
Diameter of knuckle pin and collar = 4
```

Comment: this worked for me. Could you please tell me how can I print these new values which are printing in the command window in the list.text file in the place of the older values

Comment: @kunalshegokar check the edit and if it helped you may mark the answer by clicking on the tick sign to accept it, cheers

Comment: thanks a lot this was very helpful. I got one more doubt what if I want to search a particular a particular line and only replace its text. consider here I want to search diameter of pin and only replace its value.

Comment: @kunalshegokar sure, just search for that particular line only, i.e `if line.startswith("Diameter of knuckle pin and collar")` or perhaps, search for a keyword in the line like  `find_line = line.find('knuckle pin')`

Comment: the thing is that after using this command it is deleting all the content from the file and it is only finding the searched line and printing the line in the file. I want to find the line and only change its content without deleting other content from the file

Comment: @kunalshegokar you should have mentioned that in the question. I can edit to add that on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("xyz.txt","w+")
file.write("") #whatever needs to be written
file.close()
```

what `open("xyz.txt","w+")` will do is create a file called `xyz.txt`.

**Note:** the file if not present then we use "w+" else we can do "w" if the file is present.

Every time you run your code the values present in the file will get erased and a new set of values will be written to it thereby replacing the old values

You can use this also if the file is already created

```
file = open("xyz.txt","w")
```

More information regarding file handling can be obtained from [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation).

Comment: thanks for replying but i think this will most probably delete all the content present previously and write the new line what I want to do is replace only the values without changing anything already present in the file. The .txt file I listed above is just an example but in reality, the file is much bigger and it contains a number of lines to be specific 250 lines and I want to just replace certain values

Comment: @kunalshegokar thankyou for appreciating. I hope your problem was solved by user5173426 suggestion.